# How to set two Async Pipe functions in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pipe

I have 2 functions that checks a specific condition, I would both like both of them to be true.
How would you use *ngIf in this case? Currently if I set one of them it works, but I need both of them.

HTML

```
<p *ngIf="(isFree$ | async) && (order$ | async)">Free Plan</p>
```

TS

```
public order(data) {
    const order = data.externalOrderId;
    if (order.substring(0, 4) === 'asdad') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


 public isFree$ = this.planType$.pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return (data.plan === 'Free');
    }
));
```

Comment: No I saw this; so I need but conditions to be True...how can I use and in ngIf

Comment: unable to understand!

Comment: Merge the observables and use the `map` operator to marshall them into a boolean value.

Comment: @TheHeadRush how?

Comment: It really depends on the observables you are combining. You should probably check out https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/ and see which operator best fits your use case.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale please remove the duplicate question. This is a different question

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new dumb component that has (2) Inputs: [isFree], [order]
- In your new component use an *ngIf statement to show the `<p>` if both Inputs are available.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The parent component should contain the observables and provide them as `input`s to a dumb component that has your `p`. Only show the `p` element if both inputs are defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

It will wait until both the observables streams return the response. It returns single observable array of responses to which you can subscribe or use `async` pipe to resolve

HTML

```
<p *ngIf="resp$ | async">Free Plan</p>
```

TS

```
public isFree$ = this.planType$.pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return (data.plan === 'Free');
    }
));

public isOrder$ = of({resp:[]}) // stream 2

public resp$ = forkJoin(this.isFree$, this.isOrder$)
```

[Fork join example with ngIf and async](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-single-ngif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: it seems that forkjoin has been deprecated?

Comment: @user12684453 In which version it's deprecated? I didn't think so.

Comment: it has been deprecated in rxjs

Comment: No it is not. I have already provided you the link to tutorial example. Here is the link to official docs https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin